# Android: Slider image viewPager is not showing anything

Tags: java, android, layout, android-viewpager, adapter

I have seen all the question related to this topic but didn't find solution, in my case viewpager is not showing anything, its simple image slider, moreover toast are appearing as i'm swaping but didn't see image and text, and when im adding these lines(as other solutions said)

```
 ((ViewPager) container).addView(iv, 0);
 ((ViewPager) container).addView(tv, 0);
```

it gives me error

> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

this is my main.xml file (inside relative layout):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>
```

this is viewPager adapter

```
public class ClsCustomPagerViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

int[] layouts;
String[] titles;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;

public ClsCustomPagerViewAdapter(Context context, int[] layouts, 
String[] titles) {
    this.layouts = layouts;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((ViewGroup) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View imageLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_placeholder
, container);
    TextView tv = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    Toast.makeText(context,
            "Viewpagers " + titles[position] ,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    tv.setText(titles[position]);
    iv.setImageResource(layouts[position]);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(iv, 0);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(tv, 0);
    return imageLayout;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return layouts.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}
```

and this is layout for images and textviews for viewpager adapter(inside framelayout)

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these two lines of code

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(iv, 0);
((ViewPager) container).addView(tv, 0);
```

with

```
container.addView(imageLayout);
```

**EDITED:**

Also

```
View imageLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_placeholder
, container);
```

with

```
View imageLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_placeholder
, container, false);
```

Comment: Now its saying:  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Comment: what is the difference between passing null and container to inflate

Comment: Im sorry I may have given you an old code from my app. I just recently read this article explaining this problem. Here is the link. Go check it out.                  https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: By providing null you tell the inflator not to attach the layout to any parent.That is by providing the parent itself as null. But by that article I found out that best way to do that is by providing the correct parent layout and tell the inflator not to automatically attach the layout to parent. I have edited my answer

Comment: I practiced it, I have a question why we have to first not to attach to parent (in this case ViewPager) to get its layout params, and then later on adding views to parent, why we can't attach to the parent and set resources if I do this i cant see anything, we have to manually adding views, why we can't just attach to parent and set resources and go

Comment: Sorry. But I'm afraid I dont know exactly why